# Seeing cookies duplicated when using cookies restored from a database

Tags: python, python-3.x, cookies, python-requests

I'm working with some API using [requests](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/). To keep my account authorized, I save the cookies to a database when exiting, and restore them the next time.

For some reason requests doesn't replace old cookies with new values returned by the server. It just adds a new cookie with the same name but with a different value.

Code:

```
from requests import Session
import json

local_session = Session()
local_session.cookies.update(json.loads(account.cookies))

resp = local_session.request("GET", "http://example.com/path0/")
# all cookies have been sent, server renewed some of them and return in "Set_Cookie" headers

resp = local_session.request("GET", "http://example.com/path1/")
# here requests send two cookies with same name but different values instead of one with new
```

Cookies in database:

```
{
    "csrf": "abcdefgh",
    "session": "1234567890"
}
```

Cookies sent in last request:

```
{
    "csrf": "abcdefgh",
    "csrf": "ijklmnop",
    "session": "1234567890"
}
```

What have I missed, is it possible to fix this sanely?

---

**UPD.**

I've tried in console with httpbin and ... result is same, it duplicates cookies:

```
from requests import Session

with Session() as sess:
    sess.cookies.update({"sessioncookie": "1234567890"})
    # Same behavior with sess.cookies.set('sessioncookie','1234567890')
    sess.get("https://httpbin.org/cookies/set/sessioncookie/0987654321")
    print(sess.cookies.items())
    # here's two pairs of cookies with same name now
```

Comment: What is account variable ?

Comment: @CorentinLimier, database model. Actually, it doesn't matter, cause `account.cookies` contains json string. I'm sure, that problem isn't here, cause in first request it send proper cookies.

Comment: Could you try this `print(local_session.cookies.items())` after the second request and write the result on your post ?

Comment: @CorentinLimier, actually I've done it ("Cookies sent in last request:"). `.items()` contains both pairs: with old value and with new. The problem is somewhere in storing cookies after first request.

Comment: Because I tried this : `s=Session();s.get('https://httpbin.org/cookies/set/sessioncookie/123456789');s.get('https://httpbin.org/cookies/set/sessioncookie/12345679');print(s.cookies.items()` (httbin.org gives you apis to simulate requests) and actually it updates the cookie well. Do you have the same behavior on this website ?

Comment: @CorentinLimier, try to set cookie before first request.

Comment: You are right. I think that you should update your post with this example as it is reproducible for everyone :) You get the same problem when you update the cookie after the request.

Comment: @CorentinLimier, updated my post. Hope, there's a solution.

Comment: Can you please show us how you are *saving* the cookies to the database?

Comment: @MartijnPieters, something like `account.cookies = json.dumps(dict(session.cookies))`. There's example in the bottom of question without any databases, just 4 lines of code producing same issue, so I don't think problem is there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cookies are a little more complex than *just* key-value pairs. Browsers must also track what URLs the cookies are valid for (via rules about hostnames, port numbers, URL paths and whether or not the connection would be encrypted), and how long to keep them for (their expiration). Some cookies are designed to expire the moment you close your browser and so have no expiration set.

You are not storing all that information in the database, however. You only stored the keys and values, and when you then add the cookies back to a new `requests.Session()` cookiejar, those cookies are marked as *universal and permanent*. The cookies will be sent to all URLs, will never expire, and are never discarded for any reason. This type of cookie is sometimes referred to as a *supercookie*. But the server is still also setting regular cookies with complete URL validity and expiration information, and they are *different cookies* because of those settings.

You can confirm this by iterating over the cookie objects in your sample `httpbin.org` code:

```
>>> from requests import Session
>>> sess = Session()
>>> sess.cookies.update({"sessioncookie": "1234567890"})
>>> __ = sess.get("https://httpbin.org/cookies/set/sessioncookie/0987654321")
>>> for cookie in sess.cookies: print(cookie)
...
<Cookie sessioncookie=1234567890 for />
<Cookie sessioncookie=0987654321 for httpbin.org/>
```

There are two separate cookies here, one for `/` (all paths, all domains), and one for `httpbin.org` alone. Both will be sent.

You need to persist much more information in the database to re-create 'normal' cookies. If you don't need *readable* storage, then the `requests` library explicitly makes the cookiejar pickleable:

```
import pickle

cookiedata = pickle.dumps(session.cookies, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

This is binary data, store it as such. You can restore your cookies with:

```
session.cookies.update(pickle.loads(cookiedata))
```

Otherwise, if you must have JSON then you'll have to store [all the `Cookie` attributes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.cookiejar.html#cookie-objects):

```
cookie_attrs = [
    "version", "name", "value", "port", "domain", "path", "secure",
    "expires", "discard", "comment", "comment_url", "rfc2109"
]
cookiedata = json.dumps([
    {attr: getattr(cookie, attr) for attr in cookie_attrs}
    for cookie in session.cookies
])
```

and restore from JSON with

```
for entry in json.loads(cookiedata):
    session.cookies.set(**entry)
```

Technically speaking, there is also a `_rest` attribute that tracks the `HttpOnly` attribute of cookies (in a nested dictionary), but that attribute is otherwise not ignored by `requests` as it only applies to browsers where cookies with that attribute set to `True` can't be accessed from JavaScript.

In principle, the `domain`, `path`, `name` attributes make a cookie *unique*, but if a server sets, say, a cookie with a specific `port` value, and you serialised that cookie and restored it later, now that cookie is going to be sent regardless of the port used for the target URL (everything else being equal), and that could actually break things if the site decides that seeing such a cookie anywhere else was an issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot. As far as I researched *name, value, domain, path* and *expires* is enough to recreate "normal" cookie, so I've done small wrapper to save and restore this fields (it's much more readable then `pickle.dump()`). Anyway, thank You very much for help. Choosing your answer, cause I find it more universal.

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the solution, you need to specify the domain

```
from requests import Session

with Session() as sess:
    #sess.cookies.update({"sessioncookie": "1234567890"})
    sess.cookies.set('sessioncookie','1234567890', domain='httpbin.org')
    sess.get("https://httpbin.org/cookies/set/sessioncookie/0987654321")
    print(sess.cookies.items())
    # Only one cookie
```

Comment: That's not the full solution; you haven't included path information, port, the secure flag, or the expiration date.

Comment: Put differently: you are still creating super-cookies here.

Comment: Thanks. To restore "rewritable" cookie you need to add also *path* and *expires* (`path=path='/'`, `expires=None`).